# What's the meaning of "easy" here?

Tags: word-in-context

From an American sitcom Friends S06E23, [Transcript Here](http://www.livesinabox.com/friends/season6/623ring.htm)

> [Scene: Joey and Rachel's, continued from earlier. Chandler is showing
>   Rachel the ring.]
>
> Chandler: Check out the ring.
>
> Rachel: (gasps) Nice! One and a half carat easy.

What's the meaning of "easy" here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In informal US English "easy" can be its own adverb, where you would formally use "easily". So the sentence means that the diamond is comfortably at least that much in weight.